# C++ Operator overloading for << with abstract class

Tags: c++

Here are my header files:

```
//Frame.h
#pragma once

class Frame {
    string frameName;
protected:
    double fileSize;
    vector<Attribute> attributes;
public:
    Frame(string f, double size, vector<Attribute> d) :frameName(f), fileSize(size), attributes(d) {}
    virtual ~Frame() {}
    string& GetFrameName() { return frameName; }
    Attribute& operator[](int);
    int size() { return attributes.size(); }
    virtual void Compress() = 0;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Frame&);
};

// AudioFrame
#pragma once

class AudioFrame :public Frame {
    static const int RATES = 3;
    static constexpr double BITRATE[]{128,160,192};
    static constexpr double COMPRESSION_RATIO[]{11.1,9.1,7.1};
public:
    AudioFrame(string frameName, double fileSize, vector<Attribute> d) :Frame(frameName,fileSize, d) {}
    ~AudioFrame(){}
    void Compress();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, AudioFrame&);
};


//ImageFrame.h
#pragma once

class ImageFrame :public Frame {
    static const int BITS = 8;
    static constexpr double COMPRESSION_RATIO = 6.0;
    static constexpr double BITDEPTH_FACTOR[] {11.1,4.6,3.5,2.4,1.9,1.5,1.2,1.0};
public:
    ImageFrame(string fileName, double fileSize, vector<Attribute> d) :Frame(fileName, fileSize, d) {}
    ~ImageFrame(){}
    void Compress();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, ImageFrame&);
};
```

Each one of them have a `**friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, ImageFrame&);**`
But when i do this

```
ImageFrame test;
cout << test << endl;
```

Only Frame class's operator `<<` is called. Any solution to this?
Also, professor doesn't want me to change anything from the header files!

**EDIT:**
here is how i implement the operator <<:

```
// code from AudioFrame.cpp
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, AudioFrame& obj) {
    os << "AudioFrame" << endl;
    os << "Name = " << obj.GetFrameName() << endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < obj.attributes.size(); i++) {
        os << "\tBandwidth #" << i << ": " << obj.attributes[i] << endl;
    }

    return os;
}

// code from ImageFrame.cpp
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, ImageFrame& obj) {
    os << "ImageFrame" << endl;
    os << "Name = " << obj.GetFrameName() << endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < obj.attributes.size(); i++) {
        os << "\tResolution #" << i << ": " << obj.attributes[i] << endl;
    }

    return os;
}

// code from Frame.cpp
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Frame& obj) {
    return os;
}
```

But when i run the test code, only the code from `Frame.cpp` is run.

**EDIT2:**
So i feel like i should also share my real test code:

```
int type;
deque<Frame*> frames; // all frames are stored here
// user is promoted a console menu for selecting a frame type (ImageFrame or AudioFrame)

if (type == 1)
    frames.push_back(new AudioFrame(...));
else
    frames.push_back(new ImageFrame(...));

// now when i need to print all frames i do
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < frames.size(); i++)
    cout << *(frames[i]) << endl;
```

Comment: Works fine here: https://godbolt.org/g/8syWmS, Is this really EXACTLY how you invoke the operator?

Comment: I implement the operator<< in each of the sub classes. But when i run the test code, only the base class i.e. Frame class's operator<< code is run, the subclasses's code is ignored.

Comment: Shouldn't friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, ImageFrame&); be called since it's the best match?

Comment: Can you show us your test code?

Comment: I modified my post with the implementation and test code i already posted in my initial post edit.

Comment: ImageFrame does not have a default constructor. How are you able to write ImageFrame test;?

Comment: @gchen: it does have a initial constructor:
`ImageFrame(string fileName, double fileSize, vector<Attribute> d) :Frame(fileName, fileSize, d) {}`

Comment: But that's not the default constructor -- a constructor that can take 0 argument

Comment: @gchen: if default constructor isn't there, the compiler makes one itself.

Also guys i added my main test code in EDIT2, maybe someone can catch a flaw that i cannot see at the moment!

Comment: When you have a user-defined constructor, compiler no longer provide the free default constructor for you

Comment: I now see your real test code which is completely different from your original... Put simply, compiler still see *(frames[i]) as a Frame object because there is no polymorphism

Comment: So how can i fix it?

Comment: Are you allowed to add a virtual method to the header file?

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot change the header files, nor add anything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you REALLY want `cout << *(frames[i]) << endl;` to dispatch polymorphically, and you REALLY cannot alter the headers, then you have no choice but to rely on dynamic typing.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, Frame& frame) {
  AudioFrame* as_audio_frame = dynamic_cast<AudioFrame*>(&frame);
  ImageFrame* as_image_frame = dynamic_cast<ImageFrame*>(&frame);

  if(as_audio_frame) {
    return stream << *as_audio_frame;
  }

  if(as_image_frame) {
    return stream << *as_image_frame;
  }

   //normal frame code
}
```

However, this is TERRIBLE code, and signals that some reorganizing is severely needed in the headers. So i suspect there is something wrong in your intrepretation of your assignment.

**Edit**, well, actually, there is a hilariously overengineered alternative...

```
class FrameAdapterInterface {
public:
  virtual ~FrameAdapterInterface() {};

protected:
  virtual std::ostream print(std::ostream&) = 0;
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, FrameAdapterInterface &);
};

template<typename FRAME_T>
class AdapatedFrameType : public FrameAdapterInterface {
  FRAME_T data_;
public:
  template<typename... ARGS_T>
  AdapatedFrameType(ARGS_T&&... args)
    : data_(std::forward<ARGS_T>(args)...) {}

  ostream& print(std::ostream& stream) override {
    return stream << data_; 
  }
};

ostream& FrameAdapterInterface::operator<<(ostream& stream, FrameAdapterInterface& frame) {
  return frame.print(stream);
}
```

Comment: Well i was good with a virtual function but its the professor who made the headers and doesn't want us to change them!

But awesome, this works and thank you.

Do you know how i can give reputation, i am new here!

Comment: @AgneeseSaini You gave me reputation already by accepting the answer!

Comment: Horrible code, yet fulfills the draconian preconditions.  Kids, don't emulate this at home!  (Closed course, professional developer.)